# Why InitBinder adds hours when parsing date?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm trying to parse date sent from spring form. In my controller I've added InitBinder like this:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder( WebDataBinder binder )
{
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd" );
    binder.registerCustomEditor( Date.class, new CustomDateEditor( sdf, true ) );
}
```

And I'm sending with Ajax post. Sent date is:

```
registerDateFrom: "2013-09-04"
```

While parsing this date manually gives proper result:

```
sdf.parse( "2013-09-12" )
-----
Wed Sep 04 00:00:00 CEST 2013
```

Parsing with InitBinder adds 2 hours to parsed date:

```
Wed Sep 04 02:00:00 CEST 2013
```

Where does it come from? I've tried to add TimeZone to SimpleDateFormat, but result is the same.

Comment: Is there any possibility that it's caused by "CEST" (known as "Central European Summer Time")? Your code works well on my machine (CST("China Standard Time") instead). I found "CEST is 2 hours ahead of Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)" on wikeapedia

Comment: This may be it, but question is, why is SimpleDateFormat ignoring timezone anyway? And why, it's adding hours only when parsing spring form?

Comment: all the results on the same machine?

Comment: Yes, from my local machine